# Json data is not creating the table from dropdownlist selection

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

My dropdownlist is working finely. it is hitting JsonResult and fetching the VendorList by CountryId but in ajax section this data is not creating any table to show my fetched data.

**Controller code**

```
 [HttpPost]
   public JsonResult GetVendorIdByCountryId(string countryId)
    {

        int countId;
        List<Vendor> vendorList = new List<Vendor>();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(countryId))
        {
            countId = Convert.ToInt32(countryId);
            vendorList = entity.Vendors.Where(x => x.CountryId == countId && x.VendorsStatus==true).ToList();

        }
        SearchViewModel svm1 = new SearchViewModel();
        svm1.VendorList = vendorList;

        return Json(svm1.VendorList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#ddlCountry").change(function () {

    $("#tblProducts tbody tr").remove();

    $.ajax({

        type: 'POST',

        url: '@Url.Action("GetVendorIdByCountryId")',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { countryId: $("#ddlCountry").val() },
        success: function (data) {
            var json = data;
            var $table = $('#tblVendor'); 

            $.each(json, function(i, value) {
                var $row = $('<tr />');

                $('<td />').text(value[i].VendorId).appendTo($row);
                $('<td />').text(value[i].VendorName).appendTo($row);


                $table.append($row);
            });

        },
        error: function (ex) {
            var r = jQuery.parseJSON(response.responseText);
            alert("Message: " + r.Message);
            alert("StackTrace: " + r.StackTrace);
            alert("ExceptionType: " + r.ExceptionType);
        }
    });
    return false;
})
});

</script>




<div>
    <table id="tblVendor" name="VendorList">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>VendorId</th>
                <th>VendorName</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I have tried several methods to create my table but it's not working.JavaScript is not sending my Json value to the table. I can't figure out where am I doing the mistake. I am new in .net Mvc plateform.

Comment: have you tried ActionResult instead JsonResult as method return type

Comment: Is that `return Json(svm1.VendorList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` returns correct JSON data? If it is true, then possibly you have invalid selectors when creating HTML table. Try using proper append method e.g. `var $row = $('#tblVendor tr')` & `$row.append('<td>' + value[i].VendorId +'</td>')`.

Comment: @Mujthaba Yes sir i have tried actionResult for which my CountryId selection doesn't hit to the action and i couldn't get any value. but this jsonResult helped me to hit the action

Comment: @Tetsuya sir, i already did what you said... but this also not working.